# When reloading a page, what causes Chrome Developer Tools to "forget" the currently selected element?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

It happens on some (most) sites, but not all. The problem doesn't exist in Firefox, so it must be a combination of Chrome + website code.

These are not dynamically-created elements either.

Comment: I just tried and it remembers the non generated elements for me. Does it always happen? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, @Achshar here you go:
stackoverflow.com - try the main logo
google.com - try literally any element

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I open  google.com, right click on the logo and click inspect element. Then I hit reload. The element is selected after reload.

Comment: @Flix, sounds like you use an old version of Chrome.